# export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="<yourconnectionstring>" - command line failed and dotnet crashes after

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am following the doc here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#macos

and used the mac os bash line

```
export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="<yourconnectionstring>"
```

but after running this command line, nothing shows in my console.

When I restart the visual studio and Terminal as insturction,
then run the

```
dotnet build
```

and

```
dotnet run
```

the console says

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
```

So the export connectiong string did not work. Also, the dotnet crashes.

I executed the export command line, at same level as where my app is.

What am I doing wrong? Am I at the wrong level to execute the command?

Maybe somebody can explain me what "write it to a new environment variable on the local machine running the application" means?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you change the code to read from string not from the environment to check if it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc you shared, it tried to add your connection string as an environment variable, and then tried to access it in program code.

So, you may check if the environment variable was successfully set by opening a terminal and run the command `printenv`.

Anyway, there are lots of workarounds:

1. You can just put your connection string in a config file, and read it.
2. Or, you can just hardcode it.
3. Or get it from any other ways you can (db, http and so on).

If the connection string was successfully got, your problem should be solved.

Comment: when I printenv right after export the connection string, it shows its value but when I restart the terminal and VS, then printenv returns empty. I ended up hardcode the connection string for the sake of my sanify! but thanks! wonder what is erasing it from the printenv hmm

Comment: Do you have root privilege?

Comment: @yoonvak For how to set environment in mac OS, you may refer to: [How do I set environment variables on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x)